# How do get a tcl clock value of "today"?

Tags: time, tcl

What's the best way to get the value of "today" at 12:00:00am in tcl?

To get the value of "now", I can use:

```
set now [clock seconds]
```

But this would be today at whatever hours/minutes/seconds the call was made. What if I needed it to be 12:00:00am? Do I need to resort to something like this:

```
set today [clock scan [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%d"] -format "%Y-%m-%d"]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

To get the timestamp for today at 12:00, use:

```
set timestamp [clock scan "12:00:00" -format "%H:%M:%S"]
```

or

```
set timestamp [clock scan "12:00" -format "%H:%M"]
```

To get such a timestamp for another arbitrary day, compute the *base timestamp* and then use `-base` to apply that during the above operation. (The default value for `-base` is the result of `clock seconds` at the time of the call; that's most commonly useful. Also, if you parse a date without a time then the time part is taken to be midnight of that day.)

```
set base [clock scan "2018/12/25" -format "%Y/%m/%d"]
set timestamp [clock scan "12:00:00" -format "%H:%M:%S" -base $base]
puts [clock format $timestamp]
```

You could also build the time string all at once and then just parse it in one go. Note also that a good reason for parsing the base separately is that you can create it once and reuse it several times when you're parsing a whole collection of times (which stops the interpretation of the times changing when you pass midnight during the running of your program).

---

Of course, `clock scan` will also infer you were talking about hours, minutes and seconds if you don't use the `-format` option, but that's rather flakey and not recommended if you actually know the format. (It doesn't cope well at all with non-US order dates, and the internal parser it uses in this case has some weird behaviours.)

Comment: How is your method different from mine? i.e. paring a text date?